# How to copy the source html file and save it after replacing string to another directory using php?

Tags: php, duplicates

```
 $a = trim($allDataInSheet [$i]["A"]); 
 $b=trim($allDataInSheet [$i]["B"]);
 /* copy the source file */
    $fname = "edm.html";
     copy("edm.html","hk/edm.html");
    $fcopy="hk/edm.html";

     /* read the duplicate file */
    $fhandle = fopen($fcopy,"r");
    $content = fread($fhandle,filesize($fcopy));

    /* replace the string in the duplicate file */
    $content = str_replace($a,$b, $content);
    $fhandle = fopen($fcopy,"w");
    fwrite($fhandle,$content);
    fclose($fhandle);
```

Above code was not working properly,I dont want to replace the string inside the source file.I need to take the duplicate of the source file and change the strings.Thanks in advance.Pleaes help me to fix it..

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :) How exactly is the above script not working? Are any errors produced? If so what are they?

Comment: Thanks for responce. without 'copy' function I can replace string in the sourcefile.but the above code not producing any error and strings not even chenged in both source and duplicate file also.

Comment: The variable $a and $b is undefined, string can not change. You should be paste full code.

Comment: sorry.now its working.Thanks

Comment: hi @ Calos Kao..I pasted the full code here.Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be simpler if you just use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

```
$fname = 'edm.html';
copy('edm.html', 'hk/edm.html');
$fcopy = 'hk/edm.html';

// read the file
$content = file_get_contents($fcopy);

// make the replacement
$content = str_replace($a, $b, $content);

// write the file
file_put_contents($fcopy, $content);
```

Also if you put

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

at the start of your script you will make sure that you are seeing all PHP errors.

Comment: Wow great It works.Thanks.I have one more doubt here.                                  $hkdir=mkdir("HK");                                                                               $fname = "edm.html";
$hkcopy=copy("edm.html","HK/edm_hk.html");
 if($hkcopy==1)
 {$fcopy="HK/edm_hk.html";}                                                                    after using mkdir("HK");.i got error after load the page one more time like "file already  exist".How can I skip this error???

Comment: If this has answered your original question please accept this answer. To ask further questions please create a new question as it's hard to read code from comments.

Comment: You should check the result of copy and check $content to make sure they are working correctly. The script may lack the necessary permission to read and/or copy the files.

Comment: yes ..this code is not working.I cant replace the strings in the duplicate file.I posted new question with details again.I need your help.Please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: @avudaiappanT Agreed; the question should be marked as solved. Asking more questions "after the fact" is just that; "another question".

Comment: Above code not solved yet.Then how can this shoud be marked as solved?